# Visualizing Eigenvalues

Tags: plotting, eigenvalues

I am not so adept at mathematica. Despite, indirectly, finding a few examples, I cannot find a particular plot I am looking for.

[image]

The plot you see has a clear representation of complex eigenvalues. In MATLAB, it can be created with **sgrid** function but it is not so good looking. Any suggestions?

**Premise:**

Say you have a range of eigenvalue sets for varying parameter as seen in the plot. How do you make a nice plot this?

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a starting point. I assume that your data consists of N points and looks like

`{{angle 1, radius 1, eigenvalue 1}, ... , {angle N, radius N, eigenvalue N}}`.

At first I create such a set of data randomly.

```
n = 20;
data = Transpose@{RandomReal[2 Pi, n], RandomReal[5, n],RandomReal[{0, 2},n]};
```

After that we create new sublists with the same eigenvalue using `GatherBy` :

```
data2 = GatherBy[data, Last];
eigenv = #[[1, -1]] & /@ data2;
```

And finally the Plot:

```
ListPolarPlot[#[[All, {1, 2}]] & /@ data2, 
PolarGridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True,
PlotMarkers -> {"\[Cross]", 30}, 
PlotStyle -> (ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[#, MinMax[eigenv]]] & /@ eigenv), 
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"DarkRainbow", MinMax[eigenv]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: whatever you plots looks like something I would want but I want to be able to manipulate it to exactly what I want. I do not have polar coordinates as you mention. For Gatherby I think you make individual sets only. What does eigenv does and whats with the first argument of ListPolarPlot? I am sorry, it may be trivial but I am still getting my head around #. In my case I would create set of eigenvalues for each value of parameter say $k$ which would be on the BarLegend.  Again thank you for the patience!

Comment: Can you please create such a set of data? Then I will answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a `RootLocusPlot` to me.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootLocusPlot.html

Comment: Nope sorry but root locus gives gain for the entire closed loop function. This is more on the side of being able to vary a parameters and see its affect!

Comment: @Zero I think you'd just need to run several root locus plots and overlay the results.

Comment: I have 3 parameters to be varied actually $k_1$, $k_2$ and $v_x$ (not shown here). While $k_1$ and $k_2$ are gains corresponing to two states, $v_x$ is a system parameter. The feedback is of the form $u_{fb}=k_1x_1+k_2x_2$. Now for using root locus to study the effect, you can imagine first I have to write the system in the proper form to use root locus (one gain only). This would be not so straightforward for the system parameter. I think it is not at all a viable.